# Bind custom object of list to ListBox

Tags: asp.net

All, Say you have a list of object which class is named `Person`.

```
public class Person
{
   public string name{get;set;}
   public string id{get;set;}
   public int age{get;set;}
   public Major major{get;set;}
}

public class Major{
   public string MajorName{get;set;}
   public string MajorId{get;set;}
}
```

And Say you have a `ListBox` which id is `personListBox`. and It is trying to bind with the `List` of `Person`.

```
List<Person> list= new List<Person>();
list.add(...);
...
list.add(...);

personListBox.DataSource=list;
personListBox.DataTextField = "name";
personListBox.DataValueField = "id";
personListBox.DataBind();
```

But My question is How can I convert the selected Item to `Person`?
What I image the code looks like below.

```
    protected void personListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Person item = (Person)lbBizCategory.SelectedItem;
        //string majorName = item.major.MajorName;

    }
```

Unfortunatedly, It doesn't work. Is there any way to make it ? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You probably still have a reference to your list. Try

```
 protected void personListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Person yourPerson = list.First(x => x.id == int.Parse(personListBox.SelectedValue));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We cannot directly typecast the selectedItem to the Person type..!!
Instead, we can have a Person object created 
and assign the value of the object's property to the selectedItem, which is like:

```
Person person=new Person();
person.name=personListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

By the way, we cannot add values to the list as you wrote: 
    List list= new List();
    list.add(...);
Since list can now accept only Person type; so we need to create person object,
fill the object's properties and later add the object to the list as:

```
Person person=new Person();
person.name="sagar";
person.id=1;
....
list.add(person);
```